# Shorthand for-loop to iterate through an array with both value and index

Tags: julia

Is there a convenient/shorthand way to iterate through a for loop on an array, getting both value and index?

Basic options:

```
i = 1
for file in ["foo.csv", "bar.csv"]
    ...
   i += 1
end
```

```
files = ["foo.csv", "bar.csv"]
for i in 1:length(files)
   files[i]
end
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Edit: As Matt B points out, [`pairs`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.pairs) is simple and index-safe  (if using an [`OffsetArray`](https://github.com/JuliaArrays/OffsetArrays.jl),  named tuple, dictionary etc.):

```
for (i, file) in pairs(["foo.csv", "bar.csv"])
    ...
end
```

---

One option is [`enumerate`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/iterators/#Base.Iterators.enumerate):

```
for (i, file) in enumerate(["foo.csv", "bar.csv"])
    ...
end
```

but note that enumerate doesn't necessarily provide valid indices, since it's effectively `zip(x, countfrom(1))` and would break for `OffsetArray`s.

Another that's index-safe, but requires `files` to be a variable:

```
files = ["foo.csv", "bar.csv"]
for (i, file) in zip(eachindex(files), files)
    ...
end
```

Comment: even easier: [`pairs`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.pairs)!

Comment: it also works for things like dictionaries and named tuples and such.